# Neural Network not learning - MNIST data - Handwriting recognition

Tags: c++, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient

I have written a Neural Network Program. It works for Logic Gates, but when I try to use it for recognizing handwritten digits - it simply does not learn.

Please find the code below:

// This is a single neuron; this might be necessary in order to understand remaining code

```
typedef struct SingleNeuron
{
    double                  outputValue;
    std::vector<double>     weight;
    std::vector<double>     deltaWeight;
    double                  gradient;
    double                  sum;
}SingleNeuron;
```

Then I initialize the net. I set weights to be random value between -0.5 to +0.5, sum to 0, deltaWeight to 0

Then comes the FeedForward:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < inputValues.size(); ++i)
{
    neuralNet[0][i].outputValue = inputValues[i];
    neuralNet[0][i].sum = 0.0;
    //  std::cout << "o/p Val = " << neuralNet[0][i].outputValue << std::endl;
}

for (unsigned i = 1; i < neuralNet.size(); ++i)
{
    std::vector<SingleNeuron> prevLayerNeurons = neuralNet[i - 1];
    unsigned j = 0;
    double thisNeuronOPVal = 0;
    //  std::cout << std::endl;
    for (j = 0; j < neuralNet[i].size() - 1; ++j)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < prevLayerNeurons.size(); ++k)
        {
            sum += prevLayerNeurons[k].outputValue * prevLayerNeurons[k].weight[j];
        }
        neuralNet[i][j].sum = sum;
        neuralNet[i][j].outputValue = TransferFunction(sum);
        //      std::cout << neuralNet[i][j].outputValue << "\t";
    }
    //      std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

My transfer function and its derivative is mentioned at the end.

After this I try to back-propagate using:

```
// calculate output layer gradients
for (unsigned i = 0; i < outputLayer.size() - 1; ++i)
{
    double delta = actualOutput[i] - outputLayer[i].outputValue;
    outputLayer[i].gradient = delta * TransferFunctionDerivative(outputLayer[i].sum);
}
//  std::cout << "Found Output gradients "<< std::endl;
// calculate hidden layer gradients
for (unsigned i = neuralNet.size() - 2; i > 0; --i)
{
    std::vector<SingleNeuron>& hiddenLayer = neuralNet[i];
    std::vector<SingleNeuron>& nextLayer = neuralNet[i + 1];

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < hiddenLayer.size(); ++j)
    {
        double dow = 0.0;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < nextLayer.size() - 1; ++k)
        {
            dow += nextLayer[k].gradient * hiddenLayer[j].weight[k];
        }
        hiddenLayer[j].gradient = dow * TransferFunctionDerivative(hiddenLayer[j].sum);
    }
}
//  std::cout << "Found hidden layer gradients "<< std::endl;

// from output to 1st hidden layer, update all weights
for (unsigned i = neuralNet.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    std::vector <SingleNeuron>& currentLayer = neuralNet[i];
    std::vector <SingleNeuron>& prevLayer = neuralNet[i - 1];

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < currentLayer.size() - 1; ++j)
    {
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < prevLayer.size(); ++k)
        {
            SingleNeuron& thisNeueon = prevLayer[k];
            double oldDeltaWeight = thisNeueon.deltaWeight[j];
            double newDeltaWeight = ETA * thisNeueon.outputValue * currentLayer[j].gradient + (ALPHA * oldDeltaWeight);
            thisNeueon.deltaWeight[j] = newDeltaWeight;
            thisNeueon.weight[j] += newDeltaWeight;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the TransferFuntion and its derivative;

```
double TransferFunction(double x)
{
    double val;
    //val = tanh(x);
    val = 1 / (1 + exp(x * -1));
    return val;
}

double TransferFunctionDerivative(double x)
{
    //return 1 - x * x;
    double val = exp(x * -1) / pow((exp(x * -1) + 1), 2);
    return val;
}
```

One thing I observed If i use standard sigmoid function to be my transfer function AND if I pass output of neuron to transfer function - Result is INFINITY. But tanh(x) works fine with this value

So if I am using 1/1+e^(-x) as transfer function I have to pass `Sum of Net Inputs` and with `tanh` being my transfer function I have to pass `output` of current neuron.

I do not completely understand why this is the way it is, may be this calls for a different question.

But this question is really about something else: **NETWORK IS WORKING FOR LOGIC GATES BUT NOT FOR CHARACTER RECOGNITION**

I have tried many variations/combinations of `Learning Rate` and `Acceleration` and `# hidden layers` and `their sizes`. Please find the results below:

```
AvgErr: 0.299399          #Pass799
AvgErr : 0.305071         #Pass809
AvgErr : 0.303046         #Pass819
AvgErr : 0.299569         #Pass829
AvgErr : 0.30413          #Pass839
AvgErr : 0.304165         #Pass849
AvgErr : 0.300529         #Pass859
AvgErr : 0.302973         #Pass869
AvgErr : 0.299238         #Pass879
AvgErr : 0.304708         #Pass889
AvgErr : 0.30068          #Pass899
AvgErr : 0.302582         #Pass909
AvgErr : 0.301767         #Pass919
AvgErr : 0.303167         #Pass929
AvgErr : 0.299551         #Pass939
AvgErr : 0.301295         #Pass949
AvgErr : 0.300651         #Pass959
AvgErr : 0.297867         #Pass969
AvgErr : 0.304221         #Pass979
AvgErr : 0.303702         #Pass989
```

After looking at the results you might feel this guy is simply stuck into local minima, but please wait and read through:

```
Input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = 0.0910903, 0.105674, 0.064575, 0.0864824, 0.128682, 0.0878434, 0.0946296, 0.154405, 0.0678767, 0.0666924

Input = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output = 0.0916106, 0.105958, 0.0655508, 0.086579, 0.126461, 0.0884082, 0.110953, 0.163343, 0.0689315, 0.0675822

Input = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = 0.105344, 0.105021, 0.0659517, 0.0858077, 0.123104, 0.0884107, 0.116917, 0.161911, 0.0693426, 0.0675156

Input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = , 0.107113, 0.101838, 0.0641632, 0.0967766, 0.117149, 0.085271, 0.11469, 0.153649, 0.0672772, 0.0652416
```

Above is the output of epoch #996, #997,#998 and #999

So simply network is not learning. For this e.g. I have used ALPHA = 0.4, ETA = 0.7, 10 hidden layers each of 100 neurons and average is over 10 epochs. If you are worried about Learning Rate being 0.4 or so many hidden layers I have already tried their variations. For e.g. for learning rate being 0.1 and 4 hidden layers - each of 16

```
Input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = 0.0883238, 0.0983253, 0.0613749, 0.0809751, 0.124972, 0.0897194, 0.0911235, 0.179984, 0.0681346, 0.0660039

Input = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = 0.0868767, 0.0966924, 0.0612488, 0.0798343, 0.120353, 0.0882381, 0.111925, 0.169309, 0.0676711, 0.0656819

Input = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = 0.105252, 0.0943837, 0.0604416, 0.0781779, 0.116231, 0.0858496, 0.108437, 0.1588, 0.0663156, 0.0645477

Input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]          
Output = 0.102023, 0.0914957, 0.059178, 0.09339, 0.111851, 0.0842454, 0.104834, 0.149892, 0.0651799, 0.063558
```

I am so damn sure that I have missed something. I am not able to figure it out. I have read Tom Mitchel's algorithm so many times, but I don't know what is wrong. Whatever example I solve by hand - works! (Please don't ask me to solve MNIST data images by hand ;) ) I do not know where to change the code, what to do.. please help out..

### EDIT -- Uploading more data as per suggestions in comments

[1 Hidden Layer of 32](http://textuploader.com/4a57) -- still no learning.

Expected Output -- Input is images between 0-9, so a simple vector describing which is current image, that bit is 1 all others are 0. So i would want output to be as close to 1 for that particular bit and others being close to 0 For e.g. if input is `Input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` I would want output to be something like `Output = 0.002023, 0.0914957, 0.059178, 0.09339, 0.011851, 0.0842454, 0.924834, 0.049892, 0.0651799, 0.063558` (THis is vague, hand-generated)

Here are the links of other researcher's work.

[Stanford](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/mnist.html)

[SourceForge](http://eblearn.sourceforge.net/old/demos/mnist/index.shtml) -- This is rather a library

Not only these 2, there are so many sites showing the demos.

Things are working quite fine for them. If I set my network parameters(Alpha, ETA) like them I am not getting results like them, so this is reassurance that something is wrong with my code.

### EDIT 2

Adding more failure cases

[Accelaration - 0.7, Learning Rate 0.1](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3a/1425032342920.txt)

[Accelaration - 0.7, Learning Rate 0.6](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3a/1425032545677.txt)

In both of the above cases Hidden layers were 3, each of 32 neurons.

Comment: Do you know what the expected results of your network are on the MNIST task? If you can fit xor its likely that your network is at least in the right direction towards working. How are you normalizing your input data? You may be running in to a case where your initial weights are not appropriate for your normalization scheme. Also a standard neural network will not perform terribly well on MNIST task.

Comment: I haven't dissected your code but your `TransferFunctionDerivative` can overflow for very large negative inputs. It would be better to define the derivative in terms of the sigmoid. If `s(x)` is the sigmoid value, then `ds/dx = s(x)[1 - s(x)]`.

Comment: First thing to do is to remove 9 of 10 hidden layers. Deep nets can be remarkably uncooperative even when coded right. So please leave 1 hidden layer, and let us know what happens (1 hidden layer NN can solve MNIST to a reasonable 93% accuracy at least).

Comment: @bogatron - Thanks. I just read the proof. It makes sense.

Comment: @aplassard - I am not normalizing input pixels. I think that way I am introducing a complexity. Because in order to pay for pixels which are white, I have to put a few values to -ve. So NN will try to make some sense out of those negative values. BTW my images are binary. So do you think I should really be normalizing? How? Below your comment Denis mentions you should get 0.93 accuracy out of 1. I am okay with that.. Not really asking for more than that.. ;)

Comment: @DenisTarasov I have changed the Net as per your suggestion, but still results are nowhere near. One thing I noticed about my Net, for logic gates I have to keep ETA high, almost to 10, to make it learn in 900 epochs, with 0.05 as acceptable error rate. Does this relate to some well-known-weird-behaviour?

Comment: Decrease the learning rate to 0.1 and add more hidden units. Also normalize your input data so it is centered around the mean and unit variance.

Comment: Pixels need to be normalized to 0..1 range by dividing everhing by 255. Perfomance on unnormalized pictures can be poor. Note that white pixels have value of 0 in MNIST (as opposed to usual picture coding schemes). Use 300 hidden units.  Also, how do you initialize weights? Have you checked your analytical gradients with numerical ones? Logic gates should be learnable even without momentum, only with gradient descent.

Comment: Pixels were already normalized, now in fact I tried to normalize them to zero mean and unit variance, still all in vain. I am visualizing few images using OpenCV, they are looking okay. About weights, I am generating random numbers between -0.5 to +0.5. I did not get what do you mean by `checking analytical gradients with numerical ones` - please elaborate

Comment: To make sure that your backpropagation is correct, common practice is to compare values of gradient per weight computed by backprop with numerical approximation given by (f(w+delta)-f(w))/delta where w is weight value, f is error function for whole network output (usually MSE), and delta is some small number like 0.000001. Small errors in backprop implementation can be one of the important reasons for erratic behavior that you observe.

Comment: After looking at your failure case 1 I actually wonder if it is a failure. For example "Input = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output = , 0.00537016, 0.00869929, 0.210985, 0.138066, 0.00631141, 0.0112154, 0.019901, 0.68746, 0.0596589, 0.0086186" is exactly correct classification - third number is the largest among all others. And thats true for a lot of samples. Can you please compute and show actual classification accuracy?

Comment: Yes, I also observed that, but isn't 0.21 far far away from 1.0(actual output)? Or am I missing something? Do you mean to say find the maximum value of output array and recognize that as a number? Without any threshold? I am thinking like if someone in output layer has value greater than 0.8 then only it should be recognized. This way if I pass any random image that will be classified into some number? Or do I need other classifier before that? Anyway, till you answer I will compute and post the accuracy.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Take maximum from all your outputs. No thresholds. Thats common practice. MNIST standard task is 10 class classification **between** digits. If you want NN to tell your digits from random images, you need to add "OTHER" class with appropriate training samples, or train separate classifier (digit/not digit), again with appropriate training samples.

Comment: You can probably save yourself a lot of time & effort by debugging your code with a simpler problem. I recommend you try learning the logical AND function with 2x1 network, then if that works, try learning XOR with a 2x2x2 network.

Comment: @DenisTarasov, I got your point, But there is still something wrong with the network. I am getting only `51.89%` accuracy. Training was done with 60K images, 3 hidden layers of 32 and testing with 10K images. I have no idea why this  is not working. @bogatron, I have already done that. It works for all logic gates.

Comment: AFAIK, no one knows what accuracy can be obtained with your  architecture. 32 units can be simple to small. Try 1 hidden layer with 300 neurons (known baseline system from [LeCun 1998 paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf)

Comment: I solved the puzzle. I had made the worst possible mistake. I was giving wrong input. I have used opencv to scan the images, instead of using `reshape` i was using `resize` and so input was linear interpolation of images. So my input was wrong. There was nothing wrong with the code. My network is `784 - 65 - 10`giving 96.43% accuracy. I apologize from the bottom of my heart for wasting your time. From next time onwards I will try to take care of such issues. Special Thanks to Denis!

Comment: @Adorn You should add this as an answer then.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need more than 1 hidden layer for a back-prop net such as this.  It just adds complication for no benefit.

Comment: @Robinson Yes, I am understanding this from trial and error. I am looking out for a nice article having all these explained; i am not in a mood of reading 400 pages book though this week. I would really love to leverage on top of what others have experienced

Comment: I was told it by my Professor back in the 1990's when I implemented it with many layers just for fun :).

Comment: @Robinson While it is true that a single hidden layer is sufficient to solve any problem which a multi layer back-prop net could solve (applying the Universal approximation theorem), it can be inefficient to do so. When you have a network approximating function `F` and you attach a second network representing function `G` (which is the same as adding two hidden layers), your network now approximates `H=F*G` in linear time. Depending on how complex `H` is, you may need more neurons to cover all linear combinations of terms from `F` and `G` when using only a single hidden layer.

Comment: @Ext3h yes, I also agreed. Infact to tell it more bookish terms, "The hidden layer acts as a function which tries to adapt to the data. So they need to grow only if complexity of the problem grows". Complexity is not to be confused with dimensions of the input, for e.g. do not simply add hidden layer because you have bigger image.

Comment: @Adorn If the issue is solved, please add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer is copied from the OP's comment on the question.*

I solved the puzzle. I had made the worst possible mistake. I was giving wrong input. I have used opencv to scan the images, instead of using `reshape` I was using `resize` and so input was linear interpolation of images. So my input was wrong. There was nothing wrong with the code. My network is `784 - 65 - 10` giving 96.43% accuracy.